# How do I rename the script file programatically?

Tags: google-apps-script, rename

I want to be able to rename the script that is triggered every night with a name based on which of the categories it is updating.

This alternates based on a spreadsheet that sets up which category is going to be called next.

When I look at the history for the script being run, I want to know which category it was updating by looking at the title.

Is there a way to do this with code?

Comment: You can’t rename the Scripts from app scripts but you could use a scripte that has a switch statement in it and you get pass it a parameter and have it do different things for different parameter values. Of course you could also do that with if statements

Comment: Can I ask you about the script? Filename of script you want to rename is the project of standalone type and bound script type? Or that is each file in the project? If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.